# Time Filter (selector) UI?

Tags: filter, time

What is the best UI for time filter? imagine if you wanted to see a list of sessions available between 11-12 pm on a certain day, what tool could be most helpful to you? A time Slider? a pick list (like the ones flight companies use) or other things?

This is for an agenda builder for conference app. Attendees should be able to filter sessions by time.

Comment: Also see the question "A dialog to set up working hours" http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20860/a-dialog-to-set-up-working-hours/20864#20864

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [hipmunk](http://www.hipmunk.com)? They have a very cool way of presenting flights in time. Filtering is done by dragging vertical lines to your preferred flight departing and arrival times.

Look at the screenshot below:

[image: Hipmunk's time filtering]

At the top screen, time is unfiltered.
Middle screen starts the filtering process on the departure time by clicking and dragging the line.
Bottom screen, shows only the filtered results. It's quite handy!

In this sense, flights could be your session times, and attendees would be able to drag the lines to specific times where they can assist.

Answer (score 0):

[TVdags](http://www.tvdags.se/) uses a horisontal view of what is being shown on tv. The good thing about this view is that tv-shows might not all start at a specific time (such as 11 pm) but the visitor could still get an idea of what is going to start around that time. Maybe there is an event on your conference that starts 10:55 that would be hidden if the visitor choose the time from a drop down list. This solution could fix that.